# build.phonegap PhoneGap App Crashes on Launch

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, phonegap

I built a simple Hello World-style phonegap app and QR-code installed it from the build website. Immediately on launch it crashes. According to the crash log there is a call to abort() I can't seem to find any info on this crash on the web.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the browser to see if any other errors come up?

Comment: I get the same error... did you fix it?